# My Schengen visa is expired but I'm still here in Poland. Can I go out in the country anytime even I applied for the extension of my Schengen?

Tags: filipino-citizens, poland, long-stay-visas

My Schengen visa is expired but I'm  still here in Poland. Can I go out in the country anytime even I applied  for the extension of my Schengen?  I'm a Filipino and married to a Poland citizen.

Comment: Normally an overstayer in the Schengen area can expect to be fined and/or deported and/or banned from re-entry once they present themselves to the authorities - usually at an airport on departure. Your situation is more complex because you are married to an EU citizen. You should ask your question on [expatriates.se], where they are more able to answer questions about long-term residency.

Comment: but i applied for extension of my schengen visa already. I just cant wait until its done. Bc they said i will have to get an appointment after 2 months. Thats was long waiting. I just wana know if i can go out the country and not banned because i tried to extend my visa. Were 2 years couple already. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Which city/country did you apply for the extension of the Schengen visa?

Comment: You need to talk to an immigration lawyer in Poland and not with strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

From the question I assume you are talking about an

- extension of a **residence permit** issued to a spouse of an EU-Citizen

You have applied for the extension, which has not yet been issued, and the previous permit has in the mean time expired.

The present permit is a

- **residence card for family members of citizens of the EU or of the EFTA Member States**

As a general rule as a **spouse of an EU-Citizen** you should have no problem reentering Poland.

It would, however, much simpler and more reliable, to go with your Polish spouse to the local authority and **ask**.

In most cases they will know best on how to deal such a case properly.

---

**Long Answer**:

The polish government site (Ministry of Family, Labor and Social Policy) offers an english page with extensive information

- [Registration and residence permit](https://eures.praca.gov.pl/en/looking-for-a-job-in-eu/you-are-an-eu-or-efta-citizen/living-and-working-in-poland/living-and-staying-in-poland/registration-and-residence-permit)

> **If the stay in the territory of Poland last more than 3 months**:
>
> family members of citizens of the EU or of the EFTA Member States who are not citizens of the states are obliged to obtain a **residence card for family members of citizens of the EU or of the EFTA Member States**, which is issued for a period of 5 years as a rule (or for a shorter period depending on the period of the planned stay of the citizen of the EU whom a family member joins or with whom a family member stays in the territory of Poland.

**Note**:
This page seems to have been dated as the 9th of August 2016